# Failed to create cloud build: invalid bucket on App Engine deployment from local code

Tags: google-cloud-build, google-app-engine-deploy

I am trying to deploy an app to App Engine as I have done hundreds of time with gcloud app deploy, to a new project with project id XXXXXXXXX but it continuosly gives me the same error.

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Failed to create cloud build: invalid bucket "XXXXXXXXX.cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com"; default Cloud Build service account or user-specified service account does not have access to the bucket
com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcClientException:  APPLICATION_ERROR;google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1/ArgoAdminNoCloudAudit.CreateBuild;invalid bucket "XXXXXXXXX.cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com"; default Cloud Build service account or user-specified service account does not have access to the bucket;AppErrorCode=3;StartTimeMs=1711282489877;unknown;ResFormat=uncompressed;ServerTimeSec=6.696853884;LogBytes=256;Non-FailFast;EndUserCredsRequested;EffSecLevel=none;ReqFormat=uncompressed;ReqID=9f31ed718c0c9688;GlobalID=0;Server=[2002:a05:66b4:6384:b0:3:66b9:c9b4]:4001.
End of gcloud deployment

Does anybody know what have changed in the deployment process or the permissions assignments?

I have tried with different projects and always the same. I have investigate for a couple of days but I do not find any solution. Tried giving permissions to service account and Cloud Build default service account, and still the same.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and what helped me was to ensure that the compute service API is activeted (e.g. via `gcloud services enable compute.googleapis.com`) and to bind some missing IAM's roles/editor on    `XXXXXXXXX@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com`.

Side note: I consider the GCP project ID and number to be confidental and would recommend you not to share them publicly.